# is there a word to describe " understand each other without words esp. in a teamwork"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Especially when the players work in a team for a long period and they know each other very well, therefore they can guess what teammate wanna do next even without words. Is there any word to describe this phenomenon?

Comment: Could you please post a sentence with a blank in it showing how the word is to be used? Right now , I am thinking _in sync_...

Comment: Much appreciated.  the sentence goes like " During the baskteball game, I know to whom my parter wanna pass the ball, because we have been practising for a long period and we have kind of _________.( I use TACIT AGREEMENT. I don''t know it is suitable or not and do you guys have any better words for sports only.?)

Comment: What are teamworks?

Answer (score 0):

Some use the psychological term ***telepathy*** in such situations. Literally it means:

> the ability to know what is in someone else's mind, or to communicate with someone mentally, without using words or other physical signals

or

> communication with another person by thinking rather than by using words or other signals ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/telepathy))

e.g.

> The band are clearly completely in tune with each other, with the ***telepathy*** that comes of playing together night after night, but none of the jadedness that can set in. ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/telepathy.html))

So your sentence would be:

> During the baskteball game, I know to whom my parter wants to pass the ball, because we have been practising for a long period and we have a kind of ***telepathy*** (*between us*).

I would add "between us", it sounds more natural.

I also thought of ***[anticipation](https://www.google.com/search?q=anticipation%20meaning&safe=strict&biw=1760&bih=849&sxsrf=ALeKk00lFZ59HMuD1MIgIhP5IhV36wkk9A%3A1624573016145&ei=WATVYPWhCNKDsAe-qYOgCQ&oq=anticipation%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAELEDEEYQ-QEyAggAMgIIADIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yAggAMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjICCAAyBggAEAcQHjoHCCMQsAMQJzoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoECAAQCjoLCAAQBxAeEEYQ-QFKBAhBGABQ_cgdWJbmHWCi7B1oAnACeACAAYgDiAHCDJIBBzkuNC4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj1raeMprHxAhXSAewKHb7UAJQQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)***, but its connection to prediction of someone's thoughts is too vague.

I think ***telepathy*** would be *le mot juste*. [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/telepathy) agrees:

> That thing that happens when somehow you know in your head exactly
> what your brother wants for dinner even though he hasn’t said a word?
> That could be telepathy, communication that involves none of the known
> senses.
>
> Scientists can’t quite figure out if telepathy really is possible, but
> ***you can still use the word to describe those times when you seem to know what someone else is thinking***. With telepathy, people
> communicate entirely in the mind without saying anything. If you walk
> into your favorite coffee shop and without a word the guy at the
> counter hands you your double latte, that could be telepathy.

Comment: Much appreciated. I think I got the answer from you.

Answer (score 0):

> **mutual understanding** - sympathy of each person for the other. mutual affection. sympathy - a relation of affinity or harmony between
> people; whatever affects one correspondingly affects the other; "the
> two of them were in close sympathy"  [thefreedictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=mutual%20understanding%20definition&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=mutual&aqs=chrome.0.35i39j69i57j0i67l2j0i433j0i67i433j0i20i263j0i67j0i67i433j46i199i291i433.2408j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

*At the team level, the sharing of information was reported to have improved the overall understanding players had of their teammates and the different aspects of team functioning. These arguments support linking mutual-sharing to **mutual understanding** in team sports.*  [The Sport Psychologist](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=At%20the%20team%20level%2C%20the%20sharing%20of%20information%20was%20reported%20to%20have%20improved%20the%20overall%20understanding%20players%20had%20of%20their%20teammates%20and%20the%20different%20aspects%20of%20team%20functioning.%20These%20arguments%20support%20linking%20mutual-sharing%20to%20mutual%20understanding%20in%20team%20sports), 2009